# bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm Julia

Tags: julia

Is there any implementation or package for bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in Julia?

Or is there any better way to find the  the shortest path (time) from location i to location j then to  location i′ ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular algorithm, but have you looked at [Graphs.jl's shortest path algorithms list](https://juliagraphs.org/Graphs.jl/dev/algorithms/shortestpaths/)?

Comment: Thanks @phipsgabler Yes, I did. there's no bidirectional algorithem in their list.

Comment: what is i' ?  how does your problem differ from finding the shortest path from A to B and then from B to C?   OpenStreetMapX.jl (https://github.com/pszufe/OpenStreetMapX.jl) has a method `shortest_route` that can take 3 points and find the shortest route that visits A, B, C

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel, yes that's the thing. do you know the exact name of that function? The diffrence is that, I am intersted in all, not just one path. Like to have 5 first possible shortest path (in ordered frmat)

Comment: So you are asking about finding k-shortest paths between points A and B - is that your question?

Comment: Yes, finding k shortest path and having all the nodes in a list

Comment: How does even shortest_route works? any docs?  shortest_route(m, 2, 15; routing::Symbol = :astar)